# Problem with my character counter in python

Tags: python, count, character

I am trying to make a program in python that counts the characters in a text. It works when I input text without new lines like `Hello world!` and says there are 12 characters but then when I input something like

```
Hello
world!
```

then it only counts the first line and says that there are 5 characters. )=

My code:

```
import time

print("Please answer Y or N to the following questions:")
whatTo1Do = input("Would you like to include spaces in the character count? " )
whatTo2Do = input("Would you like to include commas in the character count? " )
whatTo3Do = input("Would you like to include apostrophes in the character count? " )
whatTo4Do = input("Would you like to include maths symbols (+, <, ÷, etc.) in the character count? " )
whatTo5Do = input("Would you like to include brackets in the character count? " )
whatTo6Do = input("Would you like to include other characters (~, `, \, %, &, etc.) in the character count? " )
yas = input("Your settings are displayed above. Are they correct? ")
if yas == "Y":
    pass
elif yas == "N":
    print("Please press OK to restart.")
    time.sleep(1)
    exit()
text = input("Enter your text here to count the characters based on your settings above: ")
if whatTo1Do == "N" or whatTo1Do == "n" or whatTo1Do == "no":
    text.replace(" ", "")
if whatTo2Do == "N" or whatTo2Do == "n" or whatTo2Do == "no":
    text.replace(",", "")
if whatTo3Do == "N" or whatTo3Do == "n" or whatTo3Do == "no":
    text.replace("'", "")
    text.replace('"', "")
if whatTo4Do == "N" or whatTo3Do == "n" or whatTo3Do == "no":
    text.replace("×", "")
    text.replace("÷", "")
    text.replace("=", "")
    text.replace("-", "")
    text.replace("+", "")
    text.replace(">", "")
    text.replace("<", "")
    text.replace("^", "")
    text.replace("*", "")
if whatTo5Do == "N" or whatTo3Do == "n" or whatTo3Do == "no":
    text.replace("[", "")
    text.replace("]", "")
    text.replace("(", "")
    text.replace(")", "")
    text.replace("{", "")
    text.replace("}", "")
if whatTo6Do == "N" or whatTo3Do == "n" or whatTo3Do == "no":
    text.replace("~", "")
    text.replace("`", "")
    text.replace("@", "")
    text.replace("#", "")
    text.replace("$", "")
    text.replace("%", "")
    text.replace("&", "")
    text.replace("\ ", "")
    text.replace(" \ ", "")
    text.replace("|", "")
    text.replace("/", "")
print("There are", len(text), "characters in your text. (=")
```

What do I do to make it count both lines?

Comment: What's your code?

Comment: [my code](https://paste.debian.net/1212788/)

Comment: Paste that code into your question.

Comment: How? I'm really new here and don't even know how to edit.

Comment: And it's too long for a comment.

Comment: oh, definitely too long for a comment ;)

Comment: You're reading in one line of text using `yas = input()`.  The rest of your input is ignored.

Comment: Why and how do I fix it? By the way, the text is inserted into `text = input(...)` not `yas = input()`.

Comment: Please read the documentation of [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input), which clearly states that it "reads a line from input".

Comment: Oh. I didn't know that. How do you make it so that it reads all the lines without manually removing them?

Comment: this might be a stupid question, but how are you entering `Hello\nworld!`? I might be wrong but it seems `input` only reads the first line

Comment: I write 
`hello\nworld`
somewhere else like google docs, then paste it in.

Comment: ahh, gotcha. /15 char

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you mentioned that you paste in the multi-string input, I realized the problem (and your potential solution). `input` only reads a single line as mentioned in the comments, but looks like you need to read a multi-line input.

You can use below helper function `multi_line_input` to do that. It will break when user enters an empty string (blank input). Then in your code you can just get the length of this string as usual, and it should work.

```py
def multi_line_input(prompt: str = '') -> str:
    """Reads multiple line from user input. An empty line breaks the loop."""
    lines = []
    while True:
        line = input(prompt)
        if line:
            # Note: added strip() here to strip out spaces at end,
            # such as 'hello '
            lines.append(line.rstrip())
        else:
            break
    return '\n'.join(lines)
```

Comment: How do you call that function?

Comment: Same as like `input`

Comment: You’ll have to define the function above your code or in another module, otherwise you’ll get a NameError. Another fix to wrap all your logic in a `main` function, then you can define this one below it and still call it from `main`.